# Pure JavaScript CSS3-like animation

Tags: javascript, animation

How can I, with simple JavaScript, **without switching** classes and ids, without **jQuery** and **jQuery plugins**, remake a CSS3 animation, but only with JavaScript? In CSS3 it's so simple by using `@keyframes`, but how to do it with JavaScript? What will the code be?

How can I create an animation?

```
var start = document.getElementById("start");
start.style.animation = ... // I don't know what to do
start.style.animationname = ... //Or something like this?
```

I'm still new to JavaScript.

**UPD**

I will try to simply describe, what I need: I need a div, when I click on it, it has to move +5px to the left. But I read, that the DOM animation isn't so good, so I asked about using CSS3-like animation in JavaScript.

Comment: Look for a tutorial [like this one](http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-1/). They will show you that you can do things like `function doMove() { foo.style.left = (foo.style.left+10)+'px';} doMove();` to move an object left 10 pixels. Posts on SO are supposed to be related to a specific problem, not a broad question like this

Comment: **Unclear what you're asking**:
*Please clarify your specific problem or **add additional details** to **highlight** **exactly** what you need.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just do this:

```
var start = document.getElementById("start");

start.style.left = + 10 + 'px';
```

CSS:

```
 #start{
     -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
 }
```

This would move your element 10px to the right in .5 of a second.

**Edit** regarding your edit:

To do that you could do this:

```
function move_left(current_pos){
    var element = document.getElementById("start");
    var start_left = element.style.left;
    var end_pos = parseInt(start_left, 10) + 5; 

    if(current_pos != end_pos){
        element.style.left = element.style.left + 1 + 'px';
        current_pos = parseInt(element.style.left, 10);
        return move_left(current_pos);
    }else{
        return 'finished';
    }       
}
```

Comment: hanks, but that will just move it to 10 pixels to the left, but I need animation... You now, to create a beautiful effect...

Comment: @АртурЛукин ***Animation*** is a big word. What kind of animation do you want? What have you tried to achieve it by yourself in JavaScript?

Comment: @АртурЛукин That's what the `transition ease-in-out` does it animates the movement. See [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-awesome-apps-with-css3-animations/#fbid=kjlSTz8LX-m) for more on what `transitions` can do.

Comment: @ryan, I'm not really sure, but I think he wants to re-create those animations in pure JavaScript without the use of CSS.

Comment: @JeffNoel yea, it's really not clear what he's asking for. But if he doesn't want to use a library and doesn't want to use `@keyframes` then what I have posted is the easiest way to "animate".

Comment: Yes, I know... I don't know English at level I would like it to know, to describe you what I need to do. Yes, I want to create animation on pure JS without CSS code. I wrote: **without** jQuery and CSS. Only JS!

Comment: Yes ruan, I know... I'm a human who doesn't know English good, because I live in Latvia(it's in Europe, EU) and, probably, my English teachers weren't so good as I thought... Maybe, it's because I have just graduated basic school))

Comment: @АртурЛукин It had nothing to do with your English, I know where Latvia is, and you are never to young to learn or write good questions. Also you didn't specify that you wanted to do it without CSS you just said no jquery or jquery plugins. You also mentioned `keyframes` which is an element of CSS3 just like `transitions`. However not all of the API's in CSS3 and HTML5 are implemented equally. `Transitions` have a lot more support then `keyframes`. So if you didn't want to use jquery, or `keyframes`, then to me, `transitions` was the next logical suggestion.

Comment: @АртурЛукин, Also, I edited to show how you could do what you wanted. It's ruff but it will give you the basic idea.

Answer (score 2):

To animate you'll need to define a starting state, and a target (or finished) state and an easing function to control the rate of change.

Rather than start from scratch I'd suggest leveraging an existing solution, there is a LOT of code out there to help you do this.

Check out: https://github.com/sole/tween.js